# MS Access Query to records with same data in different fields in the same row

Tags: sql, ms-access

The title is a bit confusing but I'll explain my problem here:
So i have a database table with millions of lines of spending data broken up into different time fields (period1 - period14). Now what i need to do is write a query that will return the records where the spending in one period is equal to the spending in a different period within the same record. So basically that means if i have a reecord where the spending in period1 is $100 and then the spending in period5 is also $100, it will add that record to a new table. I tried something like the code below but since I'm very new to access it is rather complex/inefficient and also doesn't do what i need it to.

```
INSERT INTO Contracts 
SELECT *
FROM SPENDDETAIL
WHERE (SPENDDETAIL.Period1 = SPENDDETAIL.Period2 OR SPENDDETAIL.Period3 [...] OR SPENDDETAIL.Period14)
AND (SPENDDETAIL.Period1 <> 0 OR SPENDDETAIL.Period2 <> 0 [...] OR SPENDDETAIL.Period14 <> 0);
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Oh also i know this code snippet would only return the records where the period1 spend equals the spend from any of the other periods it was just a beginning attempt at making the query do what i need it to.

Comment: Do you need to cross compare all periods (for example, Period 1 vs Period 2, Period 1 vs 3, 1 vs 4, then 2 vs 3, 2 vs 4 etc.) Or just period 1 vs all other period?

Comment: Technically yes, but isn't my code accomplishing that same thing by saying find where the value in period1 is equal to that in period2 or period3 or period4 etc.  Edit: if you are referring to the fact that i only compared period1 that's because i was using this code as a proof of concept before i expanded it to cross compare all periods

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might get you started:

```
SELECT Id, Value, COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT Id AS Id, 1 AS Period, Period1 AS Value FROM SPENDDETAIL
UNION ALL
SELECT Id AS Id, 2 AS Period, Period2 AS Value FROM SPENDDETAIL
UNION ALL
SELECT Id AS Id 3 AS Period, Period3 AS Value FROM SPENDDETAIL
etc...) x
GROUP BY Id, Value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Where Id is some unique identifier for each row of the data (assuming there is such a thing).

This will give you a list of Ids and matching values.